# Nuances between the various words involving production

Tags: word-choice, nuances

What are the full nuances between 生産, 制作, 製作, 作製, and 製造?

I understand that 制作 and 製作 are associated with movie/television production, and 製造 sounds like factory production, but beyond that, I don't really have a good understanding of the differences between these words.

Edit: I should add 加工 as well, though I know that this also has a feeling of factory manufacturing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

製作

> To make products or other utilitarian objects by using tools or machines. This word can be also used to make something using scissors, glue, tape, and other tools like those used in arts and crafts.

制作

> Creating artwork, films, music, etc.
> (Mainly which contains an element of creativity”)

製造

> literally factory production.  To make large quantities. Mainly used for huge scale one.

加工

> 加工≒processing (Ex. processing industry, processed food, processed goods. etc. This word means opposite of “crude”)

Comment: What about 作製 and 生産?